# SharePoint versus .NET WebClient request

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, powershell, sharepoint

We've got an internal SharePoint website that has a large number of documents I want from it.  I have access to the page when navigating through IE and individually clicking each link to start the download of the file, but there are literally hundreds (if not thousands of files) -- so I thought I'd try to PowerShell the request so I could set it up to programmatically download in the background.  However, when I try to perform the request to get the URLs for the downloads, I keep getting access denied.  I've tried:

- Setting my proxy

  - With the UseDefaultCredentials = $true
  - With explicitly defined credentials using Get-Credential
- Setting a user-agent string assuming it may only be looking for valid browsers

But I still get the Error 401: Unauthorized.  But remember, I can open up this same URL with my IE11 browser.

Any help on what I can do to make my .NET WebClient object work against our SharePoint site, just like my IE session can, would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $p = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy('proxy', 80)
#$p.Credentials = (Get-Credential)
$p.UseDefaultCredentials = $true


$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Proxy = $p
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")

try {
    $r = $wc.DownloadString('http://www.google.com')
} catch {
    $Error[0].Exception
    $error[0].Exception.InnerException
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dangit sorry... I figured it out.  While I was setting UseDefaultCredentials property to true on the Proxy object, I also needed to set it to true on the WebClient object... sorry for the lame question.